# Using jquery.form.wizard.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

I am using "jquery.form.wizard.min.js"  for creating wizard based form i.e partitioned single form in 5 steps, problem is that on last step formm is submitted via ajax but i want to submit form normally.
is there any way to submit my form normally .[Link](http://www.eakroko.de/flat/forms-wizard.html) for demo.
[Plugin link](https://github.com/thecodemine/formwizard/blob/master/js/jquery.form.wizard.js)

Comment: please mention the plugin name or the plugin link. saying the min file name is not going to help anybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution to my problem just return "true" in

```
this.element.ajaxSubmit(options); 
return false;
```

and

```
this.element.ajaxSubmit(this.options.formOptions);
return false;
```

this portion of plugin code. And now my form is submitted normally.

In the plugin code `return false` is used to prevent the form submission normally.